# If I use an API from a non-SSL website, are browsers required to give a mixed content error?

Tags: ssl, mixed-content, secure-context

The title says it all. If I use an API from a non-SSL website, do I know I will I get a mixed content error from browsers? That is, is a mixed-content error for that case what the relevant standards require browsers to do?

Comment: That's pretty much what I'm asking. I haven't tried, I just have a client asking if I can use an API from a company that doesn't use SSL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you will get a mixed-content error. [Any insecure context 
 request/response is mixed content](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-mixed-content/#mixed-content):

> A request is mixed content if its url is not a priori authenticated, and the context responsible for loading it requires prohibits mixed security contexts.
>
> A response is mixed content if it is an unauthenticated response, and the context responsible for loading it requires prohibits mixed security contexts.

The *and the context responsible for loading it requires prohibits mixed security contexts* just means the requesting context is [secure context](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-secure-contexts/)—basically, a document with an `https` origin.

See also the [*Active content examples* section of the MDN *Mixed content* article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content#Active_content_examples):

- `<script>` (`src` attribute)
- `<link>` (`href` attribute) (this includes CSS stylesheets)
- `<iframe>` (`src` attribute)
- **`XMLHttpRequest` requests**
- All cases in CSS where a url value is used (`@font-face`, `cursor`, `background-image`, and so forth).
- `<object>` (`data` attribute)

Notice that the list includes `XMLHttpRequest` requests. (It should be updated to also include `fetch()` requests).

See also the example at https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/what-is-mixed-content#an_xmlhttprequest_example